# Viewport fit screen width and big images

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I'm trying to use a WebView for displaying a big image with the built-in multitouch and trying to avoid memory crashes.

I set the webView this way:

```
    setInitialScale(20);
    WebSettings settings = getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

And then load the following code:

```
<head>
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"
/>

</head>
<body
    style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <img
        alt="image"
        src="THE_SRC_GOES_HERE"
        id="theImage"
    >
</body>
```

The problem is that if it loads a medium image (1600x1200 for example) it works nice and the image fits the screen width.

[image]

But if the image is bigger 7300x5200 in my example, it appears like zoomed in and with the zoom out disabled.

[image]

If you want to test the images urls are:

[img1](http://images1.fanpop.com/images/photos/2600000/HQ-France-wallpapers-france-2627157-1600-1200.jpg) &
[img2](http://www.deviantart.com/download/165022929/Wallpaper_2010_by_scrumen.png)

**NOTE:** I'm not the owner of that images and I'm only using it for testing

Answer (score 4):

I think your images still end up larger than the viewport by default. Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"
/>

</head>
<body
    style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <img
        alt="image"
        src="http://www.deviantart.com/download/165022929/Wallpaper_2010_by_scrumen.png"
        id="theImage"
        style="width:100%"
    >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with that option is that the white zone you see in the first picture below the image is there even after zoom in

Answer (score 3):

Don't know the correct answer but a possible walkarround could be set the **img max-width** to a "non-very high value" for example 2*screen.width when the page is loaded

Answer (score 3):

I've actually got this working on ICS by doing something a little counter-intuitive. While others are suggesting adding `style="width:100%"` to the `img` tag, my solution is to actually add `style="height:100%"` instead.

This works for me on my Android 4.0+ devices, but unfortunately it starts partially zoomed in (so the image height fills the view) on my older devices.

1. It avoids the white space problem on all devices I tested.

   - ICS shows space on initial fully-zoomed out view, but as you zoom in, it disappears exactly as you want.
   - On older devices, there is never white space below, due to the initial zoom level.
2. The zoom is not perfect, but much better.

   - On ICS, you get exactly what you want (match the width).
   - On older devices, the zoom is significantly more manageable than what you're getting in your second example in the question.

In short, I've met your requirements on ICS and gotten you much closer to them on older devices.  I'll edit my answer if I come up with anything else, but this seems worth sharing at this point, even if imperfect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the best approach by the way. It would be perfect to get the same behavior as in ICS in the other versions

Answer (score 2):

How about this: (retracted - still doesn't work right)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"
/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body
    style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <img onload="view = new Viewport(this.width, this.height)"
        alt="image"
        src="http://orbitingeden.com/orrery/textures/stars.jpg"
        id="theImage"
    >
<script>
    Viewport = function(width, height){
        var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.set = function(){
            var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
            for(i=0; i<metas.length; i++){
                if(metas[i].name == 'viewport'){
                    metas[i].setAttribute('content','width=' + width + 
                                ', height='+ height + ', user-scalable=yes');
                    theImage.style.width = '100%';
                }
            }
        }
        this.set();
    }
    $('body').bind("gesturechange", function(event) {
        view.set();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it leaves a big empty space below the image when you zoom in too. =(

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I hadn't caught that. I'll try again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm more off a web developper, here is the code that works on android ics browser, this should work the same in a webview :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
<style>
    html,body{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #my-image{
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <img id="my-image" src="http://gachie.blog.com/files/2011/06/tour_eiffel.jpg"/>
</body>
```

I tried it as well which a much biger image (http://macjacart.ca/admin/Product_Images/8UhBphVEae.jpg) and it worked smoothly.

Hope it helps!

[EDIT]

Since I have not enough room to post it in the comments, I'll put it there :

What you want is basically to cut off the bottom of the viewport as soon as your image height takes the full screen. You need some javascript to do that, and since the javascript does not have a zoom event, it's not going to require some hacks. Since android support flash, you could try [this](http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2009/12/how-to-detect-the-browser-zoom-level-change-browser-zoo/) solution to get a zoom event. As soon as the zoom reach a certain level, which depends on image ratio, you update the css of your image with a height:100%, and set width to auto.

You can basically constrain width or height depending on which one is 100%. 
You might also want to set the height progressivelly to 100% as the user is zooming, either way you are going to see a "jump" at some point.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) post as well, this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it have the same problem: when you zoom in the image the white space below is still there